# Alert when blocked computer attempts to connect via SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I know how to block a certain Ip from connecting to my computer.  I blocked the IP by editing the /etc/hosts.deny file. Then added the line `ALL : IP`.  Is there a way for when that IP tries to connect to my computer, it displays a message in their terminal?  I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: how are you blocking the IP?

Comment: @Keltari I edited the /etc/hosts.deny file. Then added the line `SSH : IP`

Answer (score 1):

you can check /var/log/messages periodically and search for strings "sshd" and the blocked IP address on the same line using grep. Otherwise, if you want instantaneous response, i.e. an email as soon as the IP connection attempt detected, you need to install something like tripwire.

Comment: I don't want to be notified I want a message to appear for them

Answer (score 0):

According to the **hosts.deny** man page, an entry like:

```
sshd : IP_GOES_HERE : twist /bin/echo "Access Denied"
```

might do what you want.

*Caveat: I can't seem to make it work for me; but, I'm on OSX*